In laws pressure on my children staying over
Assalaamualaikum. I have been married to my husband for 17 years and we share two beautiful children alhamdullilah. However my husband does not spend any time with me. At all. He comes home early hours of the morning and sleeps most of the day. He spends most of his time on the phone, sleeping or in the bathroom. My sister in law lives in Leicester and she comes over to stay with her parents every holiday. Now the main problem is that she and her parents make plans for my children. They put a lot of pressure on me to let my children have sleepovers. I feel this is causing more of a conflict between me and my husband as he is encouraging the idea while I am totally against it. Most of this pressure comes from my sister in law. I have told my in laws nicely that I need my children to be with me at night and I don't mind them going during the day. They don't seem to understand. I don't get to enjoy holidays with my children and I feel this is really unfair. Any advice would be appreciated.
Jazakallah khair

Questions asking for personal advice are off-topic.
